# What if you dont allocate room for \0 using malloc?

Tags: c, string, malloc

From what I heard, I should allocate the memory like this in line 14:
`array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(buffer)+1));` I haven't added the 1 and still the code works perfect. I cant make it crash of return anything than 0. So, is the +1 needed or not? And if it is, what are the consequences going to be since my program runs smoothly?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 5
#define SIZE 512

int main(){
    char *array[N];
    char buffer[SIZE];
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("Give word no.%d",i+1);
        gets(buffer);
        array[i]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(buffer));
        printf("%d",strlen(buffer));
        if(!array[i]){
            printf("Program will now exit.");
            exit(0);
        };
        strcpy(array[i],buffer);
    }
```

Tried it with both +1 and without. Same results although I've seen in tutorials that it is needed.

Comment: Ignoring the other problems in your code... yes, it is needed. The fact that it works without it is just luck, sooner or later it will break.

Comment: Unrelated: You're using ```gets```. It is obsolete and dangerous, so much that it has been removed from C.

Comment: `gets(buffer);` --> [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1694036/2410359)

Comment: If your compiler isn't complaining about that stray semicolon after the closing brace, you should turn compiler warnings up.

Comment: kostas791, `printf("%d",strlen(buffer));` --> `printf("%zu",strlen(buffer));` to avoid another problem.  Use matching specifiers.

Comment: The `strcpy` call will add the sting null-terminator even if you haven't allocated space for it. That will be writing out of bounds of your allocated memory, and lead to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: As ```sizeof``` is guaranteed to be 1,  ```sizeof(char)``` is just noise.

Comment: When you do **not** use `+ 1` the memory allocated to `array[i]` will be too small. In other word, `strcpy` will write outside the allocated memory. Writing out of bounds is "undefined behavior". That means  "anything may happen". One **especially nasty** thing included in "anything" is that it may produce the expected result... so you may think your code is correct but it isn't :-(

Answer (score 3):

The +1 is needed to allocate room for the null terminator. If you don't, then you might write to the allocated array out of bounds, which is undefined behavior. [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486) Meaning it might seem to work just fine, to break mysteriously later on.

`sizeof(char)` is by definition always 1 though, so that part is not needed.

Recommendation: Use `array[i] = malloc(strlen(buffer) + 1);`

As a side note, whoever (book/teacher) told you to use `gets` should be retired and not be used as a source of learning C programming. [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: Would also recommend strdup(), which is easier to use and means you don't have to even think about adding 1 or not.

Comment: @pmacfarlane I'll refrain from recommending it until C23 goes live :)